# Use of 'from' in 'scared from something'

Tags: prepositions

Is it wrong to use 'from' in this sentence:

> He is scared from something

And what about this sentence:

> I'm scared from something

Must I use 'of' in these sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those sentences, yes. Use either 'scared of' or 'scared by'.

It is sometimes correct to use 'scared from', but it's pretty rare. As an example: "He is still scared from the last time we did that."